# Linking in Symfony

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am trying to create a link for FOSUser Bundle.. It seems pretty straight forward, but for some reason i am having a problem..

i want to create a "Login" link inside my twig.

```
<a class="Link" href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a>
```

which should direct to 
`http://localhost:9911/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/login` as defined in my controller.

Am I doing this incorrectly?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to link to routes you can just use `{{ path() }}` or `{{ url() }}` and use the name of the route as argument. I was just about to tell you that you should read the documentation, but it actually doesn't mention the login-route. Who would have guessed?

You can find out the name of a route by looking into `Resources/config/routing/*.yml`. In your case the route is named `fos_user_security_login`, therefore linking to this route is as easy as using:

```
<a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_login') }}">login</a>
```